# jQuery combination of input boxes

Tags: jquery

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="margin-top: 3px;" id="shortPeriodTable">
    <form id="shortLicenseForm" name="shortLicenseForm" action="saveShortPeriodLicense" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;"></form>

    <tbody>

        <tr id="dayRateDayRow" style="display: none;">

            <td align="center" width="30%" class="">Day Rate-(Days)</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="time_Period" id="dayRateDay" value="1" style="width: 30%;"> Day
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="amount" id="dayRateAmnt" style="width: 30%;" maxlength="4"> Rs.
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="slabRateDayRow" style="display: table-row;">
            <td align="center" width="30%" class="">Slab Rate-(Days)</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="slabRateDay11" id="slabRateDay1" maxlength="3"> Days</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="slabRateDay11Amount" id="slabRateAmnt1" maxlength="4"> Rs.</td>
            <td align="left"><img alt="Add-Row" id="addRowDaySlab" src="common/images/addrow.gif"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="dayRateMonthRow" style="display: none;">

            <td align="center" width="30%">Day Rate-(Days-MOnth)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="time_Period" id="dayRateMonth">
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="amount" id="dayRateMonthAmnt" maxlength="4"> Rs.
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="slabRateMonthRow" style="display: none;">
            <td align="center" width="30%">Slab Rate-(Days-Month)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="slabRateMonth" id="slabRateMonth1" maxlength="2"> Month</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="slabRateMonthAmount" id="slabRateMonthAmnt1" maxlength="4"> Rs</td>
            <td align="left"><img alt="Add-Row" id="addRowMonthSlab" src="common/images/addrow.gif"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="slabRateDays">
            <td align="center" width="30%"></td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="slabRateDay11" id="slabRateDay2" maxlength="3"> Days</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="slabRateDay11Amount" id="slabRateAmnt2" maxlength="4"> Rs</td>
            <td align="left"><img alt="Delete-Row" onclick="deleteRowDaySlab(this);" src="common/images/removerow.gif"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="slabRateDays">
            <td align="center" width="30%"></td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="slabRateDay11" id="slabRateDay3" maxlength="3"> Days</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="slabRateDay11Amount" id="slabRateAmnt3" maxlength="4"> Rs</td>
            <td align="left"><img alt="Delete-Row" onclick="deleteRowDaySlab(this);" src="common/images/removerow.gif"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="slabRateDays">
            <td align="center" width="30%"></td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="slabRateDay11" id="slabRateDay4" maxlength="3"> Days</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="slabRateDay11Amount" id="slabRateAmnt4" maxlength="4"> Rs</td>
            <td align="left"><img alt="Delete-Row" onclick="deleteRowDaySlab(this);" src="common/images/removerow.gif"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the above table there are combination of input boxes named `Days` and `Rs.`. The combination of these boxes should not be the same. For example in `Days` input box, if value 1 is entered  and in `Rs` input box, if 200 is entered ,the other input boxes should not contain the same combination.

If it contains the duplicate combination  the corresponding input boxes should be highlighted in red and fadeout slowly. This should happen on keypress. How to do this using jQuery?

Comment: first of all try something . You just need to handle `keyup` event and check in the input box if values are not equal.  follow this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp

Comment: tried but failed...thats the reason,am asking for help..

Comment: At least show the code you have tried.